# how to use foreach calculate the each element in the upper triangular matrix?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I want to calculate  each element in the  upper triangular matrix using the `foreach` function

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

tempdata <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
tempdata2 <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

foreach (i = 1:9, .combine='rbind') %do% {
  for (j in (i+1):10) {
    tempdata[i, j] <- i+j;
    tempdata2[i, j] <- i*j

  }
}
```

it works when I use `%do%`, but when I use %dopar% I get some nothing. 
What am I doing wrong? thank you guys. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify variables defined outside of the `foreach` loop and expect that data to be sent back to the master process. `for` loops allow that kind of side effect, but it doesn't work in parallel computing unless the workers are threads within the same process, and that isn't supported by any of the R parallel processing packages because R is single threaded.

Instead, you need to return a value from the body of the `foreach` loop and combine those values to get the desired result. In your case, you compute two values per iteration of the `foreach` loop, so you have to bundle them into a list, which means you need a more complicated combine function. Here's one way to do it:

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

comb <- function(...) {
  mapply(rbind, ..., SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
}

r <- foreach(i=1:9, .combine='comb', .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
  tmp <- double(10)
  tmp2 <- double(10)
  for(j in (i+1):10) {
    tmp[j] <- i+j
    tmp2[j] <- i*j
  }
  list(tmp, tmp2)
}

tempdata <- r[[1]]
tempdata2 <- r[[2]]
```